# Winsock UDP server

Tags: c++, winsock

Hi I am currently working on a project where we are creating a UDP server to communicate with a KUKA robot. We are able to establish the connection with the robot and exchange the data back and forth but when an event occurs such as the robot faulting out due to motor over torque or something we are unable to  jump out of our server loop because the recvfrom function is still sitting there waiting for a reply. Do y’all have any suggestions on how we could fix that?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HapticRobot.h"

#include "CMaths.h"
using namespace chai3d;


#include <winsock.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2.lib")
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


#define REFRESH_INTERVAL  0   // sec

const int kBufferSize = 1024;

extern HapticDevice hd;
extern HWND g_hWndHapticBox;
extern bool bRobotInMotion, bRobotConnectInit, bRobotConnected;
extern Handles hc;
bool err;
std::string stSend, stSendXML, stLine;
std::string stRobotStatus , stAppend;
TCHAR *chRobotStatus;


//// Prototypes ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

SOCKET SetUpListener(const char* pcAddress, int nPort);
void AcceptConnections(SOCKET ListeningSocket);
bool EchoIncomingPackets(SOCKET sd);
DWORD WINAPI EchoHandler(void* sd_);


//// DoWinsock /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The module's driver function -- we just call other functions and
// interpret their results.


int DoWinsock(const char* pcAddress, int nPort)
{
    int nRetval = 0;

    ifstream inFile("HardDisk/ExternalData.xml");
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        while ( inFile.good() )
        {
            getline ( inFile, stLine);
            stSendXML.append(stLine);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Unable to open XML file");
    }

    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Establishing the listener...");
    SOCKET ListeningSocket = SetUpListener(pcAddress, htons(nPort));
    if (ListeningSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {

        stRobotStatus = WSAGetLastErrorMessage("establish listener");
        chRobotStatus = GetStatus(stRobotStatus);
        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)chRobotStatus);
        return 3;
    }

    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Waiting for connections...");
    bRobotConnectInit = true;
    SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("Waiting for robot"));
    while (1)
    {
        if (!EchoIncomingPackets(ListeningSocket))
        {
        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)WSAGetLastErrorMessage("Echo incoming packets failed"));
        nRetval = 3;
        }
        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Shutting connection down...");
        if (ShutdownConnection(ListeningSocket))
        {
            SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Connection is down.");
        }
        else
        {
            SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)WSAGetLastErrorMessage("Connection shutdown failed"));
            nRetval = 3;
        }
        bRobotConnected = false;
        bRobotConnectInit = true;

        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Acceptor restarting...");

    }


#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    return 0;   // warning eater
#endif
}


//// SetUpListener /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Sets up a listener on the given interface and port, returning the
// listening socket if successful; if not, returns INVALID_SOCKET.

SOCKET SetUpListener(const char* pcAddress, int nPort)
{
    u_long nInterfaceAddr = inet_addr(pcAddress);
    if (nInterfaceAddr != INADDR_NONE)
    {
        SOCKET sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (sd != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            sockaddr_in sinInterface;
            sinInterface.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sinInterface.sin_addr.s_addr = nInterfaceAddr;
            sinInterface.sin_port = nPort;
            if (bind(sd, (sockaddr*)&sinInterface, 
                    sizeof(sockaddr_in)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
            //listen(sd, SOMAXCONN);

            //DWORD nThreadID;
            //CreateThread(0, 0, EchoHandler, (void*)sd, 0, &nThreadID);


                return sd;
            }
            else
            {
                stRobotStatus = WSAGetLastErrorMessage("bind() failed");
                chRobotStatus = GetStatus(stRobotStatus);
                SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)chRobotStatus);
                //cerr << WSAGetLastErrorMessage("bind() failed") <<
                //        endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}


//// EchoHandler ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Handles the incoming data by reflecting it back to the sender.

DWORD WINAPI EchoHandler(void* sd_) 
{
    DWORD Priority = CeGetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread());
    CeSetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(),Priority - 2);
    //Below is scan time in ms
    CeSetThreadQuantum(GetCurrentThread(),10);

    int nRetval = 0;
    SOCKET sd = (SOCKET)sd_;

    if (!EchoIncomingPackets(sd))
    {
        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)WSAGetLastErrorMessage("Echo incoming packets failed"));
        nRetval = 3;
    }
    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Shutting connection down...");
    if (ShutdownConnection(sd))
    {
        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Connection is down.");
    }
    else
    {
        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)WSAGetLastErrorMessage("Connection shutdown failed"));
        nRetval = 3;
    }
    bRobotConnected = false;
    bRobotConnectInit = true;
    return nRetval;
}


//// AcceptConnections /////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Spins forever waiting for connections.  For each one that comes in, 
// we create a thread to handle it and go back to waiting for
// connections.  If an error occurs, we return.

void AcceptConnections(SOCKET ListeningSocket)
{
    sockaddr_in sinRemote;
    int nAddrSize = sizeof(sinRemote);

    while (1)
    {
        SOCKET sd = accept(ListeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&sinRemote,
                &nAddrSize);
        if (sd != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            stRobotStatus = inet_ntoa(sinRemote.sin_addr);
            stAppend = "Accepted connection from ";
            stAppend.append(stRobotStatus);
            chRobotStatus = GetStatus(stAppend);
            SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)chRobotStatus);

            //chRobotStatus = GetStatus(stRobotStatus);
            //SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)chRobotStatus);

            //stRobotStatus = ntohs(sinRemote.sin_port);
            //chRobotStatus = GetStatus(stRobotStatus);
            //SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)chRobotStatus);

            bRobotConnectInit = false;
            bRobotConnected = true;
            SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("Connected to Robot"));

            //SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)inet_ntoa(sinRemote.sin_addr));
            //SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)ntohs(sinRemote.sin_port));

            DWORD nThreadID;
            CreateThread(0, 0, EchoHandler, (void*)sd, 0, &nThreadID);
        }
        else
        {
            SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)WSAGetLastErrorMessage("accept() failed"));
            return;
        }
    }
}


//// EchoIncomingPackets ///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Bounces any incoming packets back to the client.  We return false
// on errors, or true if the client closed the socket normally.

bool EchoIncomingPackets(SOCKET sd)
{
    // Read data from client

    std::string stReceive;
    std::string stIPOC;
    std::wstring stTime;
    int nStartPos, nEndPos;
    char acReadBuffer[kBufferSize], acWriteBuffer[512];
    int nReadBytes;

    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    int sockAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


    //declarations for the low pass filter
    int CURRENT_VALUE = 2;
    double T = .004, w_co, OMEGA_co, f_co;



    do
    {

        nReadBytes = recvfrom(sd, acReadBuffer, sizeof(acReadBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &sockAddrSize);

        if (nReadBytes > 0)
        {
            if (bRobotConnectInit)
            {
                bRobotConnectInit = false;
                bRobotConnected = true;
                SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("Connected to Robot"));
            }

            bRobotConnectInit = false;
            bRobotConnected = true;
        }


        stSend = stSendXML;
        stReceive = acReadBuffer;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("<IPOC>") + 6;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("</IPOC>");
        stIPOC = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);


        nStartPos = stSend.find ("<IPOC>") + 6;
        nEndPos = stSend.find ("</IPOC>");
        stSend.replace(nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos, stIPOC);


        //Raw sensor data
        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("RFx=") + 5;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("RFy=") - 2;
        hd.stRFx = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szRFx = hd.stRFx.c_str();
        hd.RFx = strtod(hd.szRFx, NULL);
        hd.RFx = hd.RFx * 0.22;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("RFy=") + 5;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("RFz=") - 2;
        hd.stRFy = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szRFy = hd.stRFy.c_str();
        hd.RFy = strtod(hd.szRFy, NULL);
        hd.RFy = hd.RFy * 0.22;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("RFz=") + 5;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("Fx") - 2;
        hd.stRFz = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szRFz = hd.stRFz.c_str();
        hd.RFz = strtod(hd.szRFz, NULL);
        hd.RFz = hd.RFz * 0.22;


        //Sensor data to be filtered
        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("Fx=") + 4;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("Fy=") - 2;
        hd.stFx = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szFx = hd.stFx.c_str();
        hd.Fx = strtod(hd.szFx, NULL);
        hd.Fx = hd.Fx * 0.22;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("Fy=") + 4;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("Fz=") - 2;
        hd.stFy = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szFy = hd.stFy.c_str();
        hd.Fy = strtod(hd.szFy, NULL);
        hd.Fy = hd.Fy * 0.22;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("Fz=") + 4;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("<IPOC>") - 3;
        hd.stFz = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szFz = hd.stFz.c_str();
        hd.Fz = strtod(hd.szFz, NULL);
        hd.Fz = hd.Fz * 0.22;

        //*Added by JMM for reading start cartesian position
        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("X=") + 3;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("Y=") - 2;
        hd.stRobotXPosition = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szRobotXPosition = hd.stRobotXPosition.c_str();
        hd.RobotXPosition = strtod(hd.szRobotXPosition, NULL);

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("Y=") + 3;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("Z=") - 2;
        hd.stRobotYPosition = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szRobotYPosition = hd.stRobotYPosition.c_str();
        hd.RobotYPosition = strtod(hd.szRobotYPosition, NULL);

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("Z=") + 3;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("A=") - 2;
        hd.stRobotZPosition = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szRobotZPosition = hd.stRobotZPosition.c_str();
        hd.RobotZPosition = strtod(hd.szRobotZPosition, NULL);  


        //Data to be passed from the HMI
        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("ForThresh=") + 11;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("StifFree=") - 2;
        hd.stForThresh = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szForThresh = hd.stForThresh.c_str();
        hd.ForThresh = strtod(hd.szForThresh, NULL);
        hd.ForThresh = hd.ForThresh/100;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("StifFree=") + 10;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("StifStick=") - 2;
        hd.stStifFree = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szStifFree = hd.stStifFree.c_str();
        hd.StifFree = strtod(hd.szStifFree, NULL);
        hd.StifFree = hd.StifFree/100;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("StifStick=") + 11;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("StifCont=") - 2;
        hd.stStifStick = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szStifStick = hd.stStifStick.c_str();
        hd.StifStick = strtod(hd.szStifStick, NULL);
        hd.StifStick = hd.StifStick/100;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("StifCont=") + 10;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("KForce=") - 2;
        hd.stStifCont = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szStifCont = hd.stStifCont.c_str();
        hd.StifCont = strtod(hd.szStifCont, NULL);
        hd.StifCont = hd.StifCont/100;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("KForce=") + 8;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("LScale=") - 2;
        hd.stKForce = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szKForce = hd.stKForce.c_str();
        hd.KForce = strtod(hd.szKForce, NULL);
        hd.KForce = hd.KForce/100;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("LScale=") + 8;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("<HMI") - 3;
        hd.stLScale = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szLScale = hd.stLScale.c_str();
        hd.LScale = strtod(hd.szLScale, NULL);

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("HapFeed=") + 9;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("<IPOC>") - 3;
        hd.stHapFeed = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szHapFeed = hd.stHapFeed.c_str();
        hd.HapFeed = atoi(hd.szHapFeed);


//data the is to be sent to the robot

        if (hd.FirstTimePosition)
        {
            hd.RobotXStartPosition = hd.RobotXPosition;
            hd.RobotYStartPosition = hd.RobotYPosition;
            hd.RobotZStartPosition = hd.RobotZPosition;         
            hd.FirstTimePosition = false;
        }

        //tells the filter to turn on or off
        if (hd.LinearScale == 0 || hd.LinearScale == 0.5 || hd.LinearScale == 1)
        {
            hd.NewScaletoRobot = 1;
            hd.stScaletoRobot = dtostr(hd.NewScaletoRobot);
            nStartPos = stSend.find ("SCX=") + 5;
            stSend.replace(nStartPos, 1, hd.stScaletoRobot);

            hd.stScaletoRobot = dtostr(hd.NewScaletoRobot);
            nStartPos = stSend.find ("SCY=") + 5;
            stSend.replace(nStartPos, 1, hd.stScaletoRobot);

            hd.stScaletoRobot = dtostr(hd.NewScaletoRobot);
            nStartPos = stSend.find ("SCZ=") + 5;
            stSend.replace(nStartPos, 1, hd.stScaletoRobot);
        }
        else
        {
            hd.NewScaletoRobot = 0;
            hd.stScaletoRobot = dtostr(hd.NewScaletoRobot);
            nStartPos = stSend.find ("SCX=") + 5;
            stSend.replace(nStartPos, 1, hd.stScaletoRobot);

            hd.stScaletoRobot = dtostr(hd.NewScaletoRobot);
            nStartPos = stSend.find ("SCY=") + 5;
            stSend.replace(nStartPos, 1, hd.stScaletoRobot);

            hd.stScaletoRobot = dtostr(hd.NewScaletoRobot);
            nStartPos = stSend.find ("SCZ=") + 5;
            stSend.replace(nStartPos, 1, hd.stScaletoRobot);
        }

        if(hd.LinearScale == 4)
        {
            f_co = 0.5;
        }
        else if (hd.LinearScale == 3)
        {
            f_co = 0.5;
        }
        else if (hd.LinearScale == 2)
        {
            f_co = 1;
        }
        else if (hd.LinearScale == 1)
        {
            f_co = 2;
        }
        else if (hd.LinearScale == 0.5)
        {
            f_co = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            f_co = 0.5;
        }

        w_co = f_co * C_TWO_PI;
        OMEGA_co = (2/T) * cTanRad((w_co * T) / 2);

        hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE] = hd.XtoRobot;
        hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE] = hd.YtoRobot;
        hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE] = hd.ZtoRobot;

        hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE] = (pow(((OMEGA_co) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)), 2)) * 
            ((hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE]) + (2 * hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] + hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 2])) 
            - (((2 * (OMEGA_co - (2 / T))) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)) * hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1])
            - ((pow(((OMEGA_co - (2 / T)) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)),2)) * hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 2]);

        hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE] = (pow(((OMEGA_co) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)), 2)) * 
            ((hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE]) + (2 * hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] + hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 2])) 
            - (((2 * (OMEGA_co - (2 / T))) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)) * hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1])
            - ((pow(((OMEGA_co - (2 / T)) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)),2)) * hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 2]);

        hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE] = (pow(((OMEGA_co) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)), 2)) * 
            ((hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE]) + (2 * hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] + hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 2])) 
            - (((2 * (OMEGA_co - (2 / T))) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)) * hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1])
            - ((pow(((OMEGA_co - (2 / T)) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)),2)) * hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 2]);


        hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];
        hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];
        hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];

        hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE];
        hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE];
        hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE];

        hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];
        hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];
        hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];

        hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE];
        hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE];
        hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE];


        //hd.CommGain = 0.001;

        //hd.XtoRobot = hd.XtoRobot / (1+(hd.CommGain * abs(hd.Fx - hd.PreviousFx)));
        //hd.YtoRobot = hd.YtoRobot / (1+(hd.CommGain * abs(hd.Fy - hd.PreviousFy)));
        //hd.ZtoRobot = hd.ZtoRobot / (1+(hd.CommGain * abs(hd.Fz - hd.PreviousFz)));


        //hd.CurrentXtoRobot = hd.XtoRobot - hd.PreviousXtoRobot;
        hd.stXtoRobot = dtostr(hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE]);
        nStartPos = stSend.find ("X=") + 3;
        stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stXtoRobot);

        //hd.CurrentYtoRobot = hd.YtoRobot - hd.PreviousYtoRobot;
        hd.stYtoRobot = dtostr(hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE]);
        nStartPos = stSend.find ("Y=") + 3;
        stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stYtoRobot);

        //hd.CurrentZtoRobot = hd.ZtoRobot - hd.PreviousZtoRobot;
        hd.stZtoRobot = dtostr(hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE]);
        nStartPos = stSend.find ("Z=") + 3;
        stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stZtoRobot);

        //hd.CurrentGtoRobot = hd.GtoRobot - hd.PreviousGtoRobot;
        //hd.stGtoRobot = dtostr(hd.GtoRobot);
        //nStartPos = stSend.find ("A=") + 3;
        //stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stGtoRobot);

        //hd.CurrentBtoRobot = hd.BtoRobot - hd.PreviousBtoRobot;
        //hd.stBtoRobot = dtostr(hd.BtoRobot);
        //nStartPos = stSend.find ("B=") + 3;
        //stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stBtoRobot);

        //hd.CurrentAtoRobot = hd.AtoRobot - hd.PreviousAtoRobot;
        //hd.stAtoRobot = dtostr(hd.AtoRobot);
        //nStartPos = stSend.find ("C=") + 3;
        //stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stAtoRobot);


        //hd.PreviousXtoRobot = hd.XtoRobot;
        //hd.PreviousYtoRobot = hd.YtoRobot;
        //hd.PreviousZtoRobot = hd.ZtoRobot;


        //hd.PreviousAtoRobot = hd.AtoRobot;
        //hd.PreviousBtoRobot = hd.BtoRobot;
        //hd.PreviousGtoRobot = hd.GtoRobot;

        strcpy( static_cast<char*>( &acWriteBuffer[0] ), stSend.c_str() );

        if (nReadBytes > 0)
        {
            int nSentBytes = 0;
            int SendLength = strlen(acWriteBuffer);
            while (nSentBytes < SendLength)
            {
                int nTemp = sendto(sd, acWriteBuffer, SendLength, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, sockAddrSize);

                if (nTemp > 0)
                {
                    nSentBytes += nTemp;
                }
                else if (nTemp == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Client closed connection before we could reply to
                    // all the data it sent, so bomb out early.
                    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Peer unexpectedly dropped connection!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (nReadBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            return false;
        }
    } while (nReadBytes != 0);

    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Connection closed by peer.");
    bRobotConnected = false;
    bRobotConnectInit = true;
    SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("Waiting for robot"));
    SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotInMotion, _T("Robot not in motion"));

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ping/pong? Timeouts? Any number of logical approaches. What have you considered so far?

Comment: You can set a timeout for the socket

Comment: BTW, [`while ( inFile.good() )` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: I inherited this project from somebody else who is no longer here how should I correct that? I am not the most experienced programmer.

Comment: We are open to any suggestions. We have never had to do any programming like this before.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to look into Asynchronous sockets, here's a URL that goes over how to use them: http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_7.shtm

Comment: Yes this'll prevent the blocking, but it'll also leave you with a zombie. Let's explore ways to robustly shut down the broken connection.

Comment: What are some of our options then?

Comment: can you post an example of how to modify how to modify our code?